# How to add self executing function inside a constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, oop, constructor, self-executing-function

I create a constructor like

```
function foo (){
    this.bar=function(){
    //something
    };
}
```

this is fine till here but i wanna add inside a self executing function
that does something when i create this object with new keyword something might look like this

```
function foo(){
    (function(){
    //do something as soon as i create this object
    })();
    this.bar=function(){
    //something
    };
}
```

I want to run a self executing function when i create a new object . So how can i do something like i wrote above

Comment: what is your exact requirement ? You want self executing function to run when you create a new object ?

Comment: This makes no sense generally speaking as you're already in a closure when you run the constructor (the constructor itself). Unless you have some really weird use-case there are usually better ways to do what you want. Besides, the second code snippet you posted works and is the answer to your question.. what about it does not work for you?